# How to notify user when he enters a specific type of place in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location, geofencing

I want to build a **flutter app** in which I want to trigger a notification when a user enters a place of a specific type.
places of specific type means (saloon, restaurants, hospital, etc) these all are types of places.

**Requirments**

- I want the system to **work offline**. (like if the user dosn't have
  mobile data & user enters the specified type of place he should
  recive a notification).
- I want the system to **work in background**.
  (when the app is terminated(killed) & user enters the specified type
  of place he should recive a notification).

**My approach**

- when the user installs the app and opens it for the first time, the
  app will cal google places API and save latitude, longitude of all
  places of specified type near him.
- and then use the **background_locator** [link](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) plugin to monitor users
  current  latitude, longitude.
- on every change of  latitude, longitude find distance between users
  latitude, longitude, and all places  latitude, longitude that we
  stored.
- if the distance is below 50 meters between users current  latitude,
  longitude, and certain place  latitude, longitude then trigger a
  notification.

**problems with my approach**

- Background service will be running all the time in background(also
  when the app is killed) witch will consume battery alot.
- As the background service will be running all the time the whole
  distance calculation will happen every 5 to 10 secs or you can say
  every the background service fetch users current location which is
  also not a good thing.
- If the user goes to any other city How will I update  latitudes,
  longiudes of the nearby places ?
- As we know some places have areas(size) and some have small, and
  distance of 50 meters will not be accurate for all places.

**What I want from you**

- If you have a better approach for solving the above problem, share it
  with me.
- if you can improve the solution that is also appreciated.
- do provide me names and links of plugins in your approach.

Comment: You can send a local notification via this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications when a user is near a location and alert him/her of whatever you want.

Comment: @OMiShah, thank you but I know how to send notifications. If you can help with other requirements that would be helpful alot.